# How do I see gradle tasks run by Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm following the course "Developing Android Apps" on udacity.
I have a problem on Lesson4A with the test suite (TestUtilities) complaining "Task 'cleanTest' not found in root project 'Sunshine'.
And then it points me to run with --stacktrace option.

But I don't know how I can run the command on the terminal in the first place.
How can I see what gradle-tasks that android studio is running?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom right corner of Android Studio you have different views:

- Gradle console
- Event Log

Additionally, if your Gradle is running, will appear a 3rd one where you can see a progress bar with some information about the process. But if you want a full details use the 2 first views.

Comment: I don't think any of those 2 views let me see the exact commands run by android studio that I can actually use on the terminal...

Comment: I know you can not see the exact command that Android Studio is running, but your question was "How can I see what gradle-tasks that android studio is running?", So technically this post answer to at least ONE of your questions

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not do the configuration at first, as the default configuration is not appropriate for this project.

1. Select **Edit Configurations** next to **Run** button on toolbar
2. Make a testing configuration, by click the **+** button and select **Android Test**.
3. Make sure you choose "Show Chooser dialog" in target device section if you are using Virtual devise like Genymotion
4. Hit **OK** and press the run button.

PS. Make sure your have this configuration under **Android Test**, and nothing under **JUnit** dropdown.

I was confused at first, but not anymore after I tried above steps from Udacity notes.

Comment: Answers from 7 years ago, we don't even have an `Android Test` section for configurations anymore.